# How should I implement this method?

Tags: java, generics, gson

Suppose I have a superclass `Entity` and some subclasses `Creature`,`Heroes` etc. I have all the data for the subclasses in JSON files which contain arrays that represent each subclass, for example the file `json/creatures/a.json` represent all the Creatures that are of type A. I'm parsing the files using gson. Here's what an example file might look like:

```
[
    {
        "name":         "Pikeman",
        "attack":       4,
        "defence":      5,
        // ...
    },
    {
        "name":         "Halberdier",
        "attack":       6,
        "defence":      5,
    }
]
```

Now I was thinking that I could make a method in Entity which parses a given JSON file and returns an instance of one of Entity's subclasses with the data it parsed. If the file only contained one entity, I could do something like

```
public static Entity parseFromJson(File file, Class<? extends Entity> c) {
    return gson.fromJson(new FileReader(file), c);
}
```

But now it gets complicated: The files contain arrays of the subclasses. Should I pass `Class<? extends Entity[]>` and make the return type Entity[] instead? If so, then where and how should I access a single element of that array? Or should I rather have just one creature per file and send the name as a string instead?

Comment: Just a note: in your example `parseFromJson`, the argument `c` is *already* a `Class` object, so you probably don't want to do `c.getClass()`, since then you're guaranteed to always get `Class.class`.

Comment: Edited now. I guess the cast is unnecessary too?

Comment: Yep.  Check [the javadoc for `gson.fromJson()`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson), it returns type `T`, so no cast is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
public static <T extends Entity> T parseFromJSON(File file, Class<T> clazz) {
    return clazz.cast(gson.FromJson(new FileReader(file), clazz));
}

public static <T extends Entity> T[] parseFromJSONArray(File file, Class<T[]> clazz) {
    return clazz.cast(gson.FromJson(new FileReader(file), clazz));
}
```

Which you could use something like (given that `gson` accepts it)

```
Foo foo = parseFromJSON(file, Foo.class);
Foo[] foos = parseFromJSONArray(file, Foo[].class);
```

Comment: If I do `Creature[] carr = Entity.parseFromJSON(new java.io.File("json/creatures/castle.json"), Creature[].class);
` it gives me `<T>parseFromJSON(java.io.File,java.lang.Class<T>) in heroes.model.Entity cannot be applied to (java.io.File,java.lang.Class<heroes.model.Creature[]>)`

Comment: @pg-robban, right, it works if `<T extends Object>`, but perhaps that's not what you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah, that does work but would it be possible to enforce some way that I can only pass arrays of (subclasses to) Entity?

Comment: @pg-robban, at the moment I can only think of putting `Class<T[]> clazz` as the second argument. But that gives you two routines, one with `[]` and one without.